# Harry Potter FanFiction where Dementors leave Azkaban in support of Voldemort and Harry creates goblins to guard Azkaban

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

The story was very well written. It had a powerful Harry and a supportive Dumbledore.

- Dumbledore takes Harry and Ginny to visit Godric Hollow/ Potter Manor (?). Eventually they meet Lilly and James via a talking photo. There is a bathtub whose bubble bath smells different for Harry and Ginny.they have a quidditch pitch in the back that they use for Harry and Neville’s birthday.
- Dementors leave Azkaban in support of Voldemort and Harry creates goblins to guard Azkaban
- Harry heals the entire long term illness ward at St. Mungo’s including Frank and Alice Longbottom and Professor Lockhart.

I might have read it on FanFiction.net or mugglenetfanfiction. Any help locating this story would be great!

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: About 5 years back